# A reminder to those with 500+ reputation: please remember your close/reopen votes!

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Even after graduation, every user on this site with 500 or more reps has the ability to [cast close and reopen votes](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). This type of votes makes sure that off-topic and unanswerable questions get removed and on-topic ones can get answered. We have [just over 60 users with 500+ reps](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=all) but only a handful appear to be reviewing questions (and answers).

**I would like to remind all 500+ rep users to please continue using these privileges when necessary.** Please remember to check the [Close](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/review/close/) and [Reopen](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) review queues regularly, and be conscientious about voting to close new questions if they shouldn't be here and voting to reopen closed questions which have been substantially improved or shouldn't have been closed in the first place.